# Modern way to connect MacOS to CUPS print server

Tags: printing, airprint, cups

What is the modern way to connect a MacOS laptop to a CUPS print server (not just individual printers), where the two systems are on different subnets (i.e. mDNS does not work)? Is it possible, or does the server need to be on the same subnet?

Possible options seem to be:

1. install `cups-browsed` (does not appear to exist on modern MacOS)
2. Configuring `client.conf` to point at remote server (this removes local printers though)
3. Setting up DNS-SD as per http://www.dns-sd.org/ServerStaticSetup.html#AirPrint

None of these appear to be a viable option to get MacOS to discover a CUPS server on a different subnet using only local changes.

"Modern" in this case should mean it works on MacOS 11 and higher.

Comment: What have you tried, which instructions have you found, how did your attempts fail?

Comment: Things looked at include: seeing if cups-browsed works on MacOS (appears not), setting server in `client.conf` (removes local printers). I have not looked at using DNS-SD yet.

Comment: Does it work within a subnet?

Comment: mDNS autoconfiguration works in a subnet, yes, as it's link-local multicast.